# Script to start and stop services automatically using crontab

Tags: shell

I want to execute my shell script on all nodes, so that it will automatically restarts if service is down. How can I achieve this ask?

Comment: What kind of OS / setup are we talking about here? I suggest you use some kind of process manager (like `systemd`) to do this for you.
If you have to use a shell script for this, you could simply wrap your service executables in a shell script with an infinite loop, ensuring the restart of the service if down.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use `Supervisor` as the same, check it from "https://askubuntu.com/questions/938781/which-to-use-systemd-or-supervisor" and choose the better in your case.